# Clearing a timer without storing it in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, settimeout, cleartimeout

Is there a way to clear a `setTimeout` without storing it in a variable and then passing it to `clearTimeout`?

Or somehow make `setTimeout` return an id instead of an object, that I would pass to `clearTimeout`?

Comment: I just came across this exact issue. Everyone is showing var id = setTimeout(...), but an did is not returned, it is an object. Did you find an answer or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myTimeout(f, ms) { 
    var id = setTimeout(f, ms); 
    return { 
       cancel : function() { 
          clearTimeout(id); 
       } 
    }; 
}

var t = myTimeout(somefunc, 5000);

// ...

t.cancel();
```